# Google reCAPTCHA is not working for IE browser.

Tags: internet-explorer, recaptcha

I need to fix recaptcha issue which is occurring only on IE (mine is 11.0.96),when I select check box for "I am not bot" the green circle spin for longtime and on browser console I am getting below error :

**SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
File: recaptcha__en.js, Line: 330, Column: 324**

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: Which website are you trying to join? Is it your website? If its not your website you could try removing the domain from your IE trusted sites list or turning off ActiveX Filtering for that site. Please provide reproduction links with your questions.

Comment: Please read the google documentation carefully. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
Your test web page has nested form elements..... you cannot do this...you must rewrite your page so that the <form> elements are not nested inside of each other.eg... NOT <form><form></form></form> BUT <form></form><form></form>

Comment: any solution to this? getting this behavior as well.